# nginx doesnt reload on crontab rule

Tags: nginx, centos7

I have installed and configured a few ssl certificates of lets encrypt
for my domains on my vps. I have the following command on my crontab file

Form time to time I am unable to access my domains because the ssl certificate
renews successfully but nginx never reloads.

```
30 2 * * 1 /usr/bin/certbot renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
35 2 * * 1 /usr/bin/systemctl reload nginx
```

As soon as I manually type
"systemctl restart nginx" the website is able to open successfully without expired ssl certificate warning. So it means the certificate is okay, but nginx didnt reload after renewal.

I am on nginx, centos 7

ANy idea why my command never reloads nginx? Even though the certificate renews successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried keeping same command in crontab and it worked for me.

Are you trying reload in crontab and using restart in manual way ?

use restart in crontab also

Comment: Hello
I just assumed it would reload nginx via crontab so when the ssl cert is renewed, nginx reload would reflect the changes

Comment: Yes It does actually

Comment: Hi, I tried /usr/bin/systemctl stop/start nginx. It's working for me. Can you try creating a bash script for reloading nginx and call that script in crontab.

Comment: I will try that.
Thank you :)